# What are some options for under decking fencing that allows access?

Tags: deck, fence, hinges, accessibility

Right now I have a deck that has vinyl lattice (diamond shaped) surrounding it.    Each piece is about 3 feet by 4 feet and is attached to support poles from the deck.

The deck is about 5 feet off the ground at the end and about 2 feet at the house.    No one will be walking under the deck.   However we put some things under the deck and we need access to take care of weeds.

There are a few parts were I don't need to make the deck accessible but I would like about 90% of it accessible, which like mentioned is mainly 3x4' openings.    I thought about putting up wood lattices with hinges but open to any ideas (current vinyl lattice is brittle and trash).

Let me also explain this is not a shopping question or asking for product advice.

Comment: Will depend on type of access.  Access as easy as a door/gate used almost daily/weekly or access once in a while?  Once in a while access can have one or two sections tied(rope/bungee straps)  to the supports.  More often you will want hinges.  Either screw wood to the vinyl(if it holds) or replace a couple of sections.

Comment: Building a hinged or dismountable "door" frame covered with the same lattice as the rest is indeed the classic solution.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to get a little putzy with things like this. I demand both a polished appearance and good usage performance as outcomes. Here's what I'd do.

I've used [Neodymium magnet sets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CYJWQYB) to act as a latch for a dog/child gate. They're crazy strong and easy to use. Nothing short of a serious thunderstorm will pull them off. The magnet carrier also has a slight recess that entraps the companion plate so they can't slide. By using them to mount lattice panels they're easily removable and, maybe more importantly, easily *reinstallable*.

[image]

1. Buy some new vinyl lattice. Find a good brand that's fairly thick. Yours may be brittle, but it must be old. New vinyl will be flexible and tough.
2. Cut panels to fit neatly between your posts.
3. Add vertical rails to the sides of your posts with about a 1" setback. Treated 2x2 would be great.
4. Temporarily mount the lattice to the rails with one screw at each end. Put the screws at future magnet locations to avoid extra, unused holes.
5. Drill through the lattice into the rails at each magnet location. this will ensure good alignment of all parts.
6. Mount two or three magnets to the rails as is appropriate for the height of the panel. Be sure they align with solid portions of the lattice.
7. Screw the companion steel plates to the lattice. Rather than the screws provided, use sleeve bolts, pop rivets, etc. for better appearance and fit. You want something that holds from the face of the lattice, and not rely solely on screw threads.

```
PLAN (TOP) VIEW

___
   | <-- post
   |
   |_____
   |     | <-- rail
   |     | 
   |_____|
   | [--]   <-- magnet
   | =================== <-- lattice
___|
```

If needed you could fasten lightweight stiffening ribs to the top and bottom of the lattice. You could also run a rail along the top, under the deck framing, to add magnets there. I'd only do these things if you find them necessary. Your panels will be small enough that I doubt you will.

Comment: I'll remember this pattern and use it somewhere. Out of curiosity on how rare earth magnets resist corrosion, I found https://www.advancedmagnets.com/corrosion-resistance-of-rare-earth-permanent-magnets-repms/ (answer: not well). If I was spec'ing something like this for somebody else, then I would have to study magnets and call for a specific one or at least a specific type. From my quick glance, it sounds like the chrome plated ones are best for outdoors. The earlier generation cobalt ones sound best, but ridiculously expensive. I saw hints of hot dip galvanized ones, but none for sale.

Comment: Very interesting answer and why I asked the question.    Why do you prefer vinyl over wood lattices?    Also why do you prefer adding a rail vs installing on the face?

Comment: @popham - I didn't think about the corrosion.    This fencing will sit below a deck that sees a lot of water and a lot runs off the front - where most of the under fencing will sit.

Comment: I prefer wood for appearance and vinyl for stability and durability. I think the slight recess would look more polished than flush butt joints or an overlap, akin to a recessed-panel cabinet door or picture frame. You do you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the ready made wood fence pickets or shadow box slats that are available at home stores? They are pressure treated and light so hinging would be easy. You could make gates and have the slats vertical, horizontal or at angles.  See photo below from Home Depot.

[image]

Comment: I am honestly thinking about this.    At first it sounds ridiculous to have ~40 of these wrapping my deck with a hinge on top.    -But I don't see a downside to this and it seems quite easy.   I guess the "downside" is how do I open 7 of these at one time when needing to put something larger underneath..   Maybe if the wind hits hard these bounce at the bottom?

Comment: @DMoore   "how do I open 7 of these at one time when needing to put something larger underneath."....  You have a barbecue and invite the neighbors.. lol

Comment: This is such a good easy idea.    In my head I can't get over two things...    The first is the probable warpage of the boards and the second is if I don't align these perfectly straight it will bug the sh^&t out of me.    Obviously you gave an alternative because the wood/vinyl lattice boards are very hard to hinge.

Comment: @DMoore  Just use stainless steel screws one inch in from each edge on the width.  Not a fan of lattice boards, spent a lot of time replaring/replacing them.